# In drools how to handle dynamic changes to Fact schema

Tags: jboss, graphql, drools

We have a GraphQL API end point from where fact data is being pulled. In GraphQL you can pull data attributes based on your requirements. ie add or remove attributes to graphql query.
So, there is a possibility that rules will also change based on the new attribute addition to GraphQL API. We are thinking of handling dynamic graphQL query and rules changes via a custom UI (Angular)

With this requirement my idea of using a PoJo driving the rules in DRL is out of the window. We don't want to change the underlying code when the API attribute changes. We want to avoid the need for recompilation and re deployments.

So, my question is, in Drools is there a way to handle changes to Fact schema dynamically without creating a PoJo?

The idea that I am thinking is to represent the rules in JSON format and then dynamically convert them to DRLs via a Rules Template. Is this feasible? Are there any advanced practitioners who have done something like this in their project?

Comment: ... so effectively your rule inputs are just glorified maps, possibly nested arbitrarily deeply?

Comment: Because you can write rules against maps or generic JSONObjects or the like. It makes them quite less efficient, but then again you're trying to use a tool for something it's not designed for.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas there is not a lot of nested depths, I am thinking in terms of UI builder mentioned in https://querybuilder.js.org/ with the rules format.